# React testing-library - check ag-grid onGridready callback is executed/not OR wait until onGridReady callaback execute

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-testing-library

I have been writing test cases for my application. In my test case, Before ag-grid get ready if trigger any actions related to ag-grid onGridready event API, it throws error like api is not defined. Because onGridready callback we receive the grid API object & stored that in variable & used inside component. So I have to wait until ag-grid onGridReady callback execute & then trigger actions.

is there any way to check ag-grid onGridready callback is executed or not in test case using testing-library?

OR

How to wait until onGridReady callback execute in test case using testing-library?

I have seen one example in ag-grid documentation which is used 'enzyme'. Here I should not use enzyme. That's why trying to achieve using testing-library

Please help me.